# Does DocumentDB support MongoDB 3.4.2?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I set up MongoDB (DocumentDB) in Azure and could not find an option to change the MongoDB version.

```
db.version() // return 3.2.0
```

Is it possible to update it to 3.4.2?

Comment: What expected behavior are you looking for? (and no, you cannot change the MongoDB version returned by DocumentDB).

Comment: I want to use aggregation operators like [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/#exp._S_in).

Comment: Worth noting that the server version reported by DocumentDB/CosmosDB using the MongoDB protocol does not imply full compatibility with commands or behaviour for the reported MongoDB server version. The server implementations are completely separate and many MongoDB commands may be partially or completely missing in DocumentDB. The current compatibility is based on using the MongoDB wire protocol for communication, with support for common commands like MongoDB's CRUD API. The feature gap should improve over time, but you currently can't make any inferences based on the reported server version.

Comment: Ok thank you. So DocumentDB is not an option for me. Sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like CosmosDB supports 3.4.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-cosmosdb-extends-support-for-mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-unique-indexes-and-more/

The list of supported MongoDB API for CosmosDB is listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support)